# curl command hang on nginx server while uploading file thourgh stdin

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, curl, node-repl

First of all, I am trying to implement a repl server for my node.js application, I've created it with the help of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/TooTallNate/2053342/f5c9cc805b6bef97d0944c43b328b54d8507dc64). everything is fine and I can connect to my repl server with this command in the localhost:

```
$ curl -sSNT. localhost:8000
Welcome to the Fun House
> echo me
echo me
> echo me again
echo me again
> bye
bye
> ^C
```

but when I try to use nginx as the reverse-proxy, this command got hanged and no output is displayed:

```
$ curl -sSNT. test.localhost:8083 -I
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

It hangs forever.
```

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. `git clone https://github.com/mostafa8026/nginx-repl-curl.git`
2. `cd nginx-repl-curl`
3. `docker-compose build`
4. add test.localhost to your hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost test.localhost
```

5. ‍`docker-compose up -d`
6. and the main problem: `curl -sSNT. test.localhost:8083 -I`

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the answers, we can try writing and then press `Ctrl+D`, but it closes the connection, as a repl server, the main purpose is to keep the connection open and send command like in the command line like this:

```
$ curl -sSNT. localhost:8000
Welcome to the Fun House
> echo me
echo me
> echo me again
echo me again
> bye
bye
> ^C
```

not like this:

```
curl -sSNT. test.localhost:8083 -I
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

echo me
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.21.1
Date: Sat, 09 Apr 2022 12:58:37 GMT
Content-Type: multipart/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

Welcome to the Fun House
> echo me
> Ended

It hangs here
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hanging because it's waiting for you to write something(file to be uploaded) to stdin

write something hit `enter` then `ctrl+D`

Test of answer

```
$ curl -sSNT. test.localhost:8083 -I
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

Here's a test 
mostafa8026    
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.21.6
Date: Sat, 09 Apr 2022 11:41:35 GMT
Content-Type: multipart/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

Welcome to the Fun House
> Here's a test 
mostafa8026
> Ended
```

Comment: You think I didn't do that :(. Did you try the reproduction steps?

Comment: I did I updated my answer with the output of what I said ? what happens when on your part when you follow my answer ?

Comment: Thanks, Now I understand what you mean. but it is also not correct. We loses the connection. I edited my question and provide more detail. Please read it again